# Why doesn't `transition` work for `object-position` in Safari?

Tags: css, safari

I'm trying to create a smooth scrolling effect for an img styled with `object-fit: cover;`. After various unsatisfactory attempts, this is working really nicely using the CSS `transition` property on the `object-position` property, when I update the latter in Javascript.

Except, it turns out, in Safari and Safari Mobile (specifically v14.1.2 and v14.7.1 respectively, but safe to say close to "latest" as of 2021-09-26).

I created a minimal working example here (which happens to do the property update in CSS, but the effect seems the same):

https://jsfiddle.net/v9fgxpb8/1/

the most important parts of which are:

**HTML**

```
<div style="height: 150px; width: 150px;">
<img id="example_1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#example_1 {
    min-width: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transition: object-position 1s;
    -moz-transition: object-position 1s;
    -o-transition: object-position 1s;
    transition: object-position 1s;
}
#example_1:hover {
    object-position: 50% 0%;
}
```

In Opera and Chrome, this results in a smooth sliding effect when hovering over the image, as it transitions from being positioned in the middle to being positioned at the top.

In Safari the re-positioning happens, but with no animation effect. Indeed, as the JSFiddle shows, the "transitioned" event never gets fired in Safari.

Nowhere can I find any suggestion that this ought not work in Safari. Indeed, other CSS properties that are equally listed as supported behave as expected. Does this simply not work, or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it’s just an unknown Safari bug and that you should log it.

Comment: Colour me incredulous, but okay, bug report submitted here: https://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html